# Move Eclipse's Find/Replace dialog to a view?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I find Eclipse's (Eclipse 3.7, Indigo, running under Mac OS X 10.6.8) Find/Replace floating dialog box to be very annoying.  Part of the time it ends up obscuring the search results.  Is there any way to have Eclipse move the Find/Replace somewhere else?  I'd like it to be a pop-up view, as I often do with the Console, Servers, Outline, and other views.  However, if it could be incorporated into the view which it's searching, that would be great, too.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse's Find / Replace dialog is a dialog, not a view, so you can't drag and drop it to one of the view areas.

Here's a [Eclipse search plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_search_plugin%3a_providing_a_better,_faster,_more_relevant_Eclipse_search.) that might work for you.  Scroll all the way to the bottom of the page to get the Software Update link.

Worst case, you could write your own Eclipse plug-in that creates a view that does a Find / Replace.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Gilbert.  I've tried the Eclipse search plugin (AKA QuickFind), but it didn't appear to change the way Eclipse behaves at all.  It's also an old plugin, last developed in 2007, I think.  I believe there's not much support for it.  I'd like to try writing my own solution, but I don't have the time for it now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Find/replace cannot be used as a view. Here are two ways to find text without obstructing the search:

1. Use incremental search (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)
2. Use the [quick search plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-search-eclipse#group-details) (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)

### Pros and cons

Both approaches behave differently from the traditional find/replace and may require some getting used to.

#### Approach 1.

It works out of the box, no need to install a plugin, but it (currently) does not support pasting nor searching for the current selection (but there is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for the latter). You can use <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> or repeat <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to jump between matches.

#### Approach 2.

This still opens a dialog, but one which integrates the search results rather than obscuring them. I suggest resizing it to have a good preview size.

The default shortcut shadows the "Show Key Assist" original, but this can be changed. It is an extra install and AFAIK only supports case sensitive searches, but it supports searching for the selection and pasting.

It shows matches across files, starting with *the* top open editor (if you have more than one visible, e.g. side by side, it sometimes does not start with the one you were last on). You can move between matches with <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> and hit enter to go back to the editor on the selected match.

---

NOTE

I suppose on OSX you can replace <kbd>CTRL</kbd> with <kbd>CMD</kbd> in keyboard shortcuts above to achieve the same, but I could not test it. The shortcuts can be customized in Preferences->General->Keys